# Cannot Access Local Windows Share by Different Name

Tags: windows, file-sharing, smb

Does anybody know why its not possible to access a local Windows share (say c$) within the same computer using a different name that resolves to the same IP address.

Example:

```
Computer Name: COMP-1  
IP Address: 192.168.1.2

Hosts File Entry: 192.168.1.2 COMP-2
```

I can access `\\COMP-1\C$` from within `COMP-1`, but I cannot access `\\COMP-2\C$` even though it points to the same IP address, i.e. itself.  It will always ask for credentials, which never work.

It should be noted that if `COMP-1` and `COMP-2` are added to DNS, then other systems can access the share using either name, just not from within the local machine.

Comment: A host file entry doesn't change the identity, so why do you expect an authentication would work to a nonexistent host?

Comment: *It will always ask for credentials, which never work.* Of course. To access self like COMP-2 you needs in credentials from COMP-2\. The request is sent to COMP-2, i.e. to your PC, but it knows that it is COMP-1, and it answers "I have no credentials for COMP-2 domain". So request fails. You may try to enter the username including its domain as COMP-1 when *It will always ask for credentials*, i.e. not "User", but "COMP-1\User".

Comment: *if COMP-1 and COMP-2 are added to DNS, then other systems can access the share using either name, just not from within the local machine.* DNS is not relative to NetBIOS authentication, it reports IP of destination only. After that successfull authentication look at the destination system what credential full name is used while accessing it as COMP-1 and as COMP-2...

Answer (score 2):

The reference to `\\COMP-2\C$` does not work because Windows specifically tests
for it and demands the user credentials.

This check was added for Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, presumably for
some obscure security reasons, and can be found in the KB article
with the rather long name:
[Error message when you try to access a server locally by using its FQDN or its CNAME alias after you install Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1: "Access denied" or "No network provider accepted the given network path"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd)

Its effect is that file sharing can work via the computer name, with or without
full qualification, or by the IP Address. By default, however, file-sharing
will not work with arbitrary DNS aliases.
To enable file-sharing and other Windows services to work with DNS aliases,
you must make registry changes as detailed below and reboot the machine.

> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type `regedit`, and then click OK.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`
> 3. Right-click `MSV1_0`, point to  **New**, and then click *Multi-String Value*.
> 4. In the **Name** column, type `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then press ENTER.
> 5. Right-click `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then click Modify.
> 6. In the **Value** data box, type the CNAME or the DNS alias, that is used for the local shares on the computer, and then click **OK**.
>
>    Note Type each host name on a separate line.
>
>    Note If the `BackConnectionHostNames` registry entry exists as a REG_DWORD type, you have to delete the `BackConnectionHostNames`
>      registry entry.
> 7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

I have tested this 15-year old KB article, and it still works,
and without the need for restarting the computer.
When `BackConnectionHostNames` contains `COMP-2` then the credentials
are not demanded.

To my surprise, after deleting `BackConnectionHostNames`, the credentials
were still not demanded, as probably they were implicitly generated at the time
and still remembered by Windows.